# Games similar to X-Wing?

Tags: recommendations, star-wars-x-wing

Recently I played the X-Wing miniature game and I'd like to find a game that is similar to that,  but not collectible. I don't want to buy lots of ships to play as I like.

**EDIT**: As @PhillipKendall suggested, this are some aspects of the game I like:

- Strategic game
- Squad set up
- Unit movement
- Possibility of having special skills for each unit

Is there something like that?

Comment: In order for this to be answerable, you should add details as to which aspects of X-Wing make it enjoyable for you.

Comment: @PhilipKendall Game recommendations are off topic for this site.